# stored_procedure in mysql

Tags: c#, php, mysql, stored-procedures

I write stored_procedure in my database mysql (wamp server) the stored procedure dont work.

1. I have login form in c# and I want to check username and password
2. I have table (USERS) in the table I have tow fields

   a. ID  type varchar (50)

   b. PASSWORD type varchar (50)
3. MY stored procedure name (SP_LOGIN)

I write it like this :

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_LOGIN(IN ID VARCHAR(50),IN PASSWORD VARCHAR(50)  )
  BEGIN
  SELECT *  FROM USERS WHERE ID=ID AND PASSWORD=PASSWORD;
  END //
DELIMITER ;
```

where is the error

Comment: The stored procedure seems ok... do you have the error msg?

Comment: no I dont have eroor message in php but I have eroor message in visualstudio

Comment: WHAT is that message contains?

Comment: Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized.

Comment: That is not a MySQL problem, that means that you don't have properly configured your C# connection to MySQL and the command will no execute any without connection.

Answer (score 1):

Try to rename your variables name because they are the same as column name

Comment: can you elaborate it more